# Unable to reset Input field of <p-password> of primeng angular

Tags: angular, forms, passwords, angular-reactive-forms, primeng

I am trying to reset the component `<p-password>` provided by primeng but not able to reset.
I am using reactive forms.

Demo Link: https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-password-demo-hkkgph?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

The reset works when I use

```
<input type="password"
            formControlName="password"
            [feedback]="false"
            pPassword
            />
```

but not on `<p-password>`.

Comment: Please accept answer and upvote if it is helpful. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is a bug in the p-password of primeng angular. However, you can resolve that issue by providing element reference in HTML and set value from the component.

provided HTML reference using #password as below:

```
<form [formGroup]="passForm">
  <h5>Show Password</h5>

  <p-password #password formControlName="password" [toggleMask]="true" [feedback]="false">
  </p-password>

  <input class="p-mt-3" type="password" formControlName="password" [feedback]="false" pPassword/>

</form>

<button class="p-mt-3" (click)="reset()"> RESET</button>
```

in your component side code:

```
import { ChangeDetectorRef, Component, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { Password } from 'primeng/password';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styles: [
    `
      :host ::ng-deep .p-password input {
        width: 15rem;
      }
    `
  ]
})

export class AppComponent {
  value3: string;
  passForm: FormGroup;
  @ViewChild('password') password: Password;

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {
    this.makeForm();
  }

  makeForm() {
    this.passForm = this.fb.group({
      password: [null, Validators.required]
    });
  }

  reset() {
    this.passForm.reset(); // To reset input field.
    this.password.input.nativeElement.value = ''; // To reset p-password.
  }
}
```

Comment: Yeah this works well. One thing I also noticed that after I reset form, then using another button I call makeForm() method then the form resets properly. But if I call makeForm() just after form reset it does not work. Weird.

Answer (score 2):

[SOLVED]: Its an issue with primeng version 11.3.0.
Update to version 11.4.4. will resolve the issue.